# npm installs succesfully but still calls "none was installed"

Tags: angular, ubuntu, npm, installation

I am currently trying to install firebase and angularfire2 with e on my ubuntu, and it is giving me trouble with the packages (angular/common, angular/core, angular/platform-browser, angular/platform-browser-dynamic, angular/compiler)

I keep installing one with a success output, and then get a warning saying the package is not installed (as you can see in code, here an example withe angular/compiler bu)

thanks a lot for your time/help

```
~/Documents/PiPle $ sudo npm install @angular/compiler@5.0.0 -g --save
/usr/local/lib
└─┬ @angular/compiler@5.0.0 
  └── tslib@1.9.0 

 ~/Documents/PiPle $ npm cache clean 
 ~/Documents/PiPle $ sudo npm install @angular/platform-browser@5.0.0 @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.0.0 -g --save
/usr/local/lib
├── @angular/platform-browser@5.0.0 
└── @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.0.0 

npm WARN @angular/platform-browser@5.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser@5.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@5.0.0 but none was installed.
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you have installed the core angular packages.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can decipher you need to install all required angular packages, not just `platform-browser` and `compiler`.

Run this command as well:

`$ sudo npm install @angular/core@5.0.0 @angular/common@5.0.0 -g --save`

Not sure why it complains about `compiler` since it looks like it should have installed it. It should run fine later when you run the app since it's only a warning.